# What is the Prerequisite to Understand Mathematical Analysis I?

Tags: analysis, reference-request

I am a teenager looking to learn analysis over the summer. I have taken an interest in [Mathematical Analysis I](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540874518) and [Mathematical Analysis II](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540874534) by Vladimir Zorich. I have taught myself the techniques of single variable calculus. Is that enough? If not, what would you recommend as a prerequisite? If you think there is another book you think would be better for me you can recommend it.

Comment: Zorich is way too hard for high school. Try something abit more lightweight. I would argue that you should not get too far ahead of your level. Instead, try to practice your methods of proof and do some contest level mathematics. These should prepare you for university and a career in mathematics.

Comment: You could try Spivak's Calculus, a classic text. http://www.amazon.com/Calculus-4th-Michael-Spivak/dp/0914098918